# Blum complexity measure for lambda calculus

Tags: complexity-theory, lambda-calculus

Is there a formal complexity measure for lambda expressions which satisfies the Blum axioms and measures the complexity of reducing the expression to its normal form?

I assume that the complexity measure would have to operate on the Godelization of the lambda expression, as in "Gödelization in the Untyped lambda-Calculus" (Mogensen, 1999).